# Trying to pass a table from a container into a pyspark variable and use it's columns in a select statement

Tags: loops, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have multiple delta tables inside of an ADLS container, for each of these tables I want to generate a script that converts them into parquet files and explicitly lists the columns from each table. This is what I have at the moment but it's not creating different select statements, just dumping all the columns from all tables into a single select statement:

```
df = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES IN gold")
df_rows = df.collect()
table_names = [row["tableName"] for row in df_rows]
 
for table_name in table_names:
    df = spark.sql("SHOW COLUMNS IN gold." + table_name)
    df_rows = df.collect()
    column_names = [row["col_name"] for row in df_rows]
    select_statement ="spark.sql('SELECT " + ",".join(column_names) + "FROM gold." +tablename + "').write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save('/mnt/gold/toParquet/" + tablename +"'"
```

How can I get an output that would look like this:

> spark.sql('SELECT column1,column2,etc FROM
> gold.table1').write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save('/mnt/gold/toParquet/Table1')
>
> spark.sql('SELECT column1,column2,etc FROM
> gold.table2').write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save('/mnt/gold/toParquet/Table2')
>
> spark.sql('SELECT column1,column2,etc FROM
> gold.table3').write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save('/mnt/gold/toParquet/Table3')

Comment: df = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES IN gold")
df_rows = df.collect()
table_names = [row["tableName"] for row in df_rows]

for table_name in table_names:
    df = spark.sql("SHOW COLUMNS IN gold." + table_name)
    df_rows = df.collect()
    column_names = [row["col_name"] for row in df_rows]

    select_statement = "spark.sql('SELECT " + ",".join(column_names) + " FROM gold." + table_name + "').write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save('/mnt/gold/toParquet/" + table_name + "')"
    print(select_statement)
could you try this

Comment: That produced the same outcome of all columns into a single select statement

Comment: Provide your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the `select_statement` variable with each iteration. You'll need to use a list and append to it instead.

```
df = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES IN gold")
df_rows = df.collect()
table_names = [row["tableName"] for row in df_rows]

select_statements = []
for table_name in table_names:
    df = spark.sql("SHOW COLUMNS IN gold." + table_name)
    df_rows = df.collect()
    column_names = [row["col_name"] for row in df_rows]
    select_statements.append("spark.sql('SELECT " + ", ".join(column_names) + " FROM gold." + table_name + "').write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save('/mnt/gold/toParquet/" + table_name +"')")

for statement in select_statements:
    print(statement+"\n")
```

There were a few syntax errors in your `select_statement` values as well. This code should work.

Comment: Yup it works, thank you! Also seeing the syntax errors you mentioned now, really appreciate it.